# Still getting a blank page while running my program

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my first java web application, I'm using eclipse and glassfish while trying to display a table of data and images, my servlet still showing a blank page and I don't know why.
This is my Servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    switch(action) {
            case "Afficher":
            List<Article> list;
            try {
                list = AllDao.getAll();
                request.setAttribute("list",list);
                String page = "/ViewMenu.jsp";
                request.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(request, response);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }break;
            default:
                request.getRequestDispatcher("AllServlet?action=Afficher").forward(request, response);
                }
```

}

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific I'm afraid. Do you even know you're getting into `doGet()` ? There is just so many places a web app can go wrong you need to give some more info what makes you think it is in here ?

Comment: you need to show your UI code and any relevant configurations.